# Laravel: how model gets injected from route parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've seen the following route:

```
Route::prefix('/users/{user}')->group(function () {
   Route::get('groups/{group}', 'UserGroupController@show');
}
```

And in **UserGroupController**:

```
use App\Group;

    public function show(Request $request, User $user, Group $group)
    {
        dd($group);
    }
```

My question is how does the `$group` model object gets constructed here from a raw route parameter string?

My guess is laravel's service container does the following magic
(maybe sth like

1. Injecting the Group model,
2. then do sth like `Group::where('id', $group)->first()`

but unsure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guess right. There is a binding in the core [service provider](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/194b7f9eced36605608706c54c3b530e5475e754/RouteBinding.php) which retrieves model. The bound model is the same if you would call:

```php
$temp = new Group
$model = Group::where($temp->getRouteKeyName(), request()->route('group'))->firstOrFail();
```

UPD. Actualy just found where [it happens](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/2ee1f00c223d44d96aece7b811cb13abcf0be5b6/Eloquent/Model.php#L1881):

```php
    /**
     * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation  $query
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  string|null  $field
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
     */
    public function resolveRouteBindingQuery($query, $value, $field = null)
    {
        return $query->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value);
    }
```